# Install a package manually by downloading it and unfolding into site-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, package

I want to work with the package `sparsesvd` and ran the installation as described on the [website](https://pypi.org/project/sparsesvd/):

`pip install sparsesvd`

However, this results in:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`

Now I downloaded the file `sparsesvd-0.2.2.tar.gz` from the website, assuming that I should be able to store it in the right location myself. Using an naive approach and just copying the entire folder to:

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

Does not let me import `sparsesvd` in Python. What can I do to install this package manually?

Comment: Package was last updated 25 Dec 2013 and supported Python 2.5-7 and 3.2. Conda's archive only goes back to Python 3.4, so I'd try a Python 2.7 environment.

Comment: Even after creating/activating a 2.7 environment, I receive an `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1` when trying to install sparsesvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any change of environment (so in Python 3.7), running the command:

```
pip install sparsesvd
```

worked for me, after I downloaded the [Visual Studios build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
python3 -m pip install sparsesvd
```

Comment: Thank you Giorgos. Now I get: `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Should I look for a folder names 'python3'?

Comment: @Emil So it means you haven't iinstalled python3.

Comment: If you do `python -m pip install sparsesvd `, does it work?

Comment: That leads to the same error as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797657/anaconda-prompt-wont-download-sparsesvd-command-errored-out-with-exit-status

Comment: Are you running the commands in a conda environment?

Comment: Yes, in the Anaconda Prompt

Comment: Try to update `pip`: `conda update pip` and try again

Comment: I just updated it and then ran `pip install sparsesvd`. But that gives me the same error as before

Comment: Are you able to install this package yourself? A colleague of mine got the same error and thus, I expect the reason might be on the package developer's side

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
pip3 install sparsesvd
```